# PHP: session seems to be lost after header redirect only on IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I can't find a good answer for this anywhere.
I have a login page, and after a good login it redirects to main page.
In FF, and chrome - works perfect. On IE it doesn't work. I keep losing the session when I get to the main page.

I have checked the following:
- session_start at top
- no blanks or anything befoer header redirect
- one line before the redirect, IE knows the session user id, but after the redirect, just one line after the session start, it loses the session user id
- I've checked it also on other computer - same results

What is wrong with IE? or what could be wrong with my script ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Problem solved. I can't find the logic behind this solution, but although I had session_start() at the top of the page, I added another session_start() just before writing the session vars.

Answer (score 0):

- Set PHP's `error_reporting` to `-1`; reproduce error; check logs
- Check IE's privacy settings--`$_SESSION` relies on either a cookie or URL-based session identifier. It seems as though it's having trouble saving the cookie
- Is there anything you're doing to the response that is not standard (eg modifying headers)
- Can you build an extremely simple version of this code and test it using nothing but the bare essentials (narrow down the problem to a specific bit of code)

[Edit]

- Make sure you aren't calling `session_start()` twice ;)

Comment: Great! To avoid future problems like this, I suggest getting _very_ intimate with your error log. I am almost positive PHP warns you about this type of stuff.